# App can't access jquery plugins after upgrading from Angular 4 to 6

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, webpack

Jquery plugins which used to work fine, now don't as I have upgraded from Angular 4 to 6.

I get such errors:

> TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
>
> TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

etc

My vendor.ts file contains these (same as Angular 4 setup, no change):

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'select2/dist/js/select2';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker';
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work? Am i missing something?

My components have been using jquery as

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'; //can use $ thereafter in the class
```

I am using Webpack 4 (Upgraded this from the 2.x branch as well).

I am **not** using Angular CLI

Comment: if you do `declare var $: any;` in the file where you are using datepicker and other jQuery stuff; this error will go away. It will pick jQuery plugins on runtime. 

(optional) In addition you can import those dependencies in `index.html`

Comment: i tried that, didn't work, and i already do import them in my index.html :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is an Angular 6 upgrade issue, and not a webpack issue? I had the same symptoms but fixed by editing the webpack config to include:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'jquery': require.resolve('jquery'),
...
```